# Why was the software for Apollo missions written in assembly and not in a high level programming language?

Tags: assembly, lisp, programming-languages

According to [this article](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.1201-fm.html) and answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739561/1097451), the software that was used for the Apollo 11 mission, that landed the first man on the Moon, was **written in assembly**.

I find this quite shocking, since the project started in 1960 and the mission took place in 1969. By this time already several high level programming languages were available. For example Lisp, which is a fairly high level language, even with **garbage collecting** and that is still in use today.

Given the assumption that garbage-collected high level languages reduce the potential for human error in programming and the high risk aversion of the authorities, *why did the managers allow for such a tremendous hazard?*

Comment: then and into the 1980s assembly was still used for day to day applications, not that it isnt still because it is, just not as common as then.

Comment: Garbage Collection and dynamic memory management introduce new problems: memory overflows, no real-time response, possibly bugs in the GC and memory management code, memory fragmentation, memory overhead, ...

Comment: Just because they had invented languages doesnt mean that was a wise idea for several reasons.  man mission has avoided most of the languages from the last couple/few decades as well..

Comment: The hardware technology used in space and particular man missions is also usually decades old for good reason.

Comment: Using lisp would have been a massive risk, same with fortran or other languages of the time.  assembly was very much the safe soltion, both the widespread use, and as today, many layers of review.  Same reason old tech is used, not new.  significantly lower risk.

Comment: Lisp is not the right language for every problem (Peter Norvig & Kent Pitman, Lisp style guide, page 20)

Comment: GC introduces new problems, you don't need dynamic memory allocation for this kind of applications, so there's no need to manage heap, and no risk of memory leaks. In this aspect using some high level language with GC & dynamic memory allocation would actually made the things lot more complicated, less efficient, and the code would be larger (more opportunities for bugs). Back in that era with single task SW the coder often designed the memory usage by hand, putting variables at optimal places between code. Not in A11, but sometimes even nasty kind of trickery was used to save space (pun int.)

Comment: Besides that I'm not sure why you find using Assembly so risky, the total code for A11 mission was not that big (I think it was written within 5 years?), and straightforwardly written assembly with focus on readability and maintainability can look like a bit cumbersome and over-verbose high level language, there's not *that* big difference between reasonably written assembly and lisp source.

Comment: The GC Lisp has in early days were a simple mark and sweep. People usually restarted their lisp so that they didn't get to need GC since when it started you basically had to wait for it to finish. For a system in space a system that suddenly goes offline to do GC would not work if the system is required to respond to input at any time.

Comment: In 1969, if you wanted a successful mission, you **needed good developers** with a lot of experience. You know, like 15-20 years or more. Using a new high level language like Pascal (two years old then) in a mission-critical role would be like using Rust today. Nobody with decades of experience is going to do that.

Comment: Assembly language eliminates the step of verifying that the machine-language output of the high level language's compiler matches the design intent. Assembly languages are usually free of ambiguities; the instructions execute step by step. There is no "unspecified evaluation order". Well-designed instruction sets have no "undefined behavior" and have straightforward ways to deal with exceptional situations (division by zero, integer overflow): issues which can be fairly loose in higher level languages.

Comment: Assembly language was used well into the 80's. The WordPerfect word processor was writen in assembly language, as were most games and serious applications for 8 bit microcomputers (which faced the same painful memory and CPU power constraints as minicomputers and mainframes of previous generations).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the hardware specifications (2 K RAM, 36 K hard wired memory) only manually crafted assembly language is efficient enough to do anything useful. A high level language compiler usually generates a lot of superfluous code and inefficient memory handling because it is general purpose. The software in Apollo 11 was very specific and testing several KBytes of code properly should be doable given the preparation time.

Comment: Thank you! But do you believe that these hardware specifications were given at the start of the project, or were they a result of the decision to use assembly? That is, if the decision to use assembly came first, then the decision makers could have chosen the limited hardware specs consequently, since these resources would suffice.

Comment: The article explains that the computer had to be very small (you can't carry huge machines into space), very reliable and probably energy efficient. These requirements seem much more important to me than that the computer should be easily programmable using high level (wasteful) languages

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Note that the Apollo 11 mission was in 1969. 2k RAM was a rather high amount of memory back then, especially if you consider that it has to resist space radiation.

Answer (score 7):

Wiki article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer

Most (but not all) of the program was hard coded into read only core memory.  One of the reasons for using all NOR gates in the computer is that they were radiation resistant. Although the wiki article later mentions RAM and ROM, RAM really means read + write core memory,and ROM means read only core memory.

All of the Apollo missions that went to the moon, including Apollo 11, used the Block II version of the AGC, which had 36 kilo-words (72 kilo-byte) of read only core memory for the program, and 2 kilo-words (4096 bytes) of read + write core memory (some of which was used for portions of the program to allow some in flight changes).

Getting back to the OP's question, the instruction set used on the AGC (Apollo Guidance Computer) was not high level language friendly. It was a multi-threaded (single core) program. Considering the relatively small size of the code, less than 36,000 instruction words, and with relatively few changes made to the code over the years, it would have taken significantly longer to create and test some type of compiler.

In the early years of the 8 bit home computers and game consoles, almost all of the games and other programs written for those systems were written in assembly, and typically ranged from 16KB to 64KB in size.